# expected initializer before '*' token

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I am trying to create a console application that utilizes sockets and ncurses with help from a networking book that I am using. On compilation, I get the error 'expected initializer before '*' token for the line:

```
WINDOW* create_newwin(int height, int width, int starty, int startx);
```

I didn't get this error before i included some new headers that I forgot to include, primarily networking headers.

//headers I had before error

```
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <string.h>
```

//headers I added when error started throwing

```
#include <stdio.h>      //for printf() and fprintf()
#include <sys/socket.h> //for socket(), connect(), send(), and recv()
#include <arpa/inet.h>  //for sockaddr_in and inet_addr()
#include <unistd.h>     //for close()
#include <iostream>
#include "DakchatHeader.hpp"
```

I know it's the headers because when I comment them out that specific error goes away (but errors crop up about unknown functions etc.).

It should also be noted that when I call it it says unknown function and that WINDOW is defined in ncurses.

Thanks for all help you can give me!

Comment: That error likely means that `WINDOW` hasn't been declared yet before `create_newwin()` tries to use it. Or worse, that `WINDOW` has been declared as a preprocessor macro that expands to code that is invalid in the context of `create_newwin()`'s return value. Where and how is `WINDOW` declared exactly?

Comment: @RemyLebeau WINDOW is created in ncurses

Comment: @Versalys For those of us that don't use ncurses, can you show the actual declaration of `WINDOW`? And does your code editor have a "find declaration" feature? If so, then restore all of the header files, reproduce the error, and then do a "find" and make sure it is actually finding ncurse's version of `WINDOW` and not something else that is also called `WINDOW`. And then start removing headers 1 AT A TIME until the error comes back, then you will know which header is causing the problem. Please provide a [mcve] to demonstrate the error in action.

Comment: @John3136 read the question m8. It says #include ncurses.h. So yes, I am including ncurses.h.

Comment: I figured it out. In My custom header file didn't have a semicolin after a struct i made. Did that and it fixed the error. Should have known better than to use this platform anyway because every time I ask a question my rep takes a hit. Anyway to take the question down before I get to 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my DakchatHeader.hpp file I included I forgot to add a semicolin after i created my struct. After fixing that the error was no longer shown.

Comment: That's why you make a [mre]. Too bad that we don't call them "Minimal, **Complete, and Verifiable** examples" anymore.